# Hadoop unzip error

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to tar hadoop file, while doing that getting below error

```
tar -xzvf hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the [wrong link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf4Rl.png) to download Hadoop. After the first link, [there is a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xteDq.png), where the real download address is.

Comment: I doubt this is relevant one year later

Answer (score 0):

The file looks corrupted, try by downloading another file. You can try below before downloading

`file hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz` it will show the file type, based on that you can try  with other commands

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from the location:

https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.7.3/

hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz.mds files contains the checksum

> MD5 = 34 55 BB 57 E4 B4 90 6B  BE A6 7B 58 CC A7 8F A8
>
> SHA1 = B84B 8989 3426 9C68 753E  4E03 6D21 395E 5A4A B5B1

and so on..

after downloading the file, hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz, you can use the command

```
md5sum hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
```

to generate the md5 checksum. Make sure it is same on as mentioned in the hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz.mds file.